# JavaScript Async Loop does not return result

Tags: javascript, loops, asynchronous, logic

I was having some logic problem when trying to do a function in JavaScript. Basically I have a pointArr to store the coordinates along the route. Then I got a moveNext() which takes in each coordinates along the route and plot onto the map. Then inside the moveNext(), I got another array which is busList. If the coordinates along the route match the coordinates of busList, then I minus the totalBusStopLeft by one. Here is the code where I call the moveNext():

```
 getAllBusLoc(function(busList) {
            //At first I set the totalBusLeft by the length of busList which is 13 in this case
            var totalBusLoc = busList.length;
            document.getElementById("busStopLeft").innerHTML = totalBusLoc;
            //Then I set the value to busList for the minus calculation
            busLeft = totalBusLoc;
            timeout = 1500;
            pointArr.forEach(function(coord,index){
                setTimeout(function(){
                    moveNext(coord.x, coord.y, index, busList, busLeft);
                }, timeout * index);
            });
        });

function moveNext(coordx, coordy, k, busList, busLeft){
document.getElementById("busStopLeft").innerHTML = busLeft;
//pointToCompare is the coordinates in the route but not the coordinates of busList
var pointToCompare = coordx + "," + coordy;

//If the coordinates in route matches the coordinate in busList, I minus busLeft by one
if(busList.indexOf(pointToCompare) > -1){
     parseFloat(busLeft--);
}

//Code to Add marker

}
```

However, with this code, my Html component busStopLeft keep showing 13 which is the totalBusLoc but not the busLeft. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

```
    totalBusLoc = busList.length;
            document.getElementById("busStopLeft").innerHTML = totalBusLoc;
            timeout = 1500;
            pointArr.forEach(function(coord,index){
                setTimeout(function(busLeft){
                    moveNext(coord.x, coord.y, index, busList, totalBusLoc);
                }, timeout * index);
            });
        });


function moveNext(coordx, coordy, k, busList, totalBusLoc, callback){
var pointToCompare = coordx + "," + coordy;
if(busList.indexOf(pointToCompare) > -1){
     parseFloat(totalBusLoc--);
     document.getElementById("busStopLeft").innerHTML = totalBusLoc;
     callback(totalBusLoc);
}
}
```

Comment: i think it is because of asynchronous task inside that foreach loop. try to add a counter for each moveNext being called inside forEach and subtract the counter for each completion. return final answer only when the counter is 0. or find a better module for doing async loops

Comment: @user3932668 Sorry but what do you mean by return final answer only when the counter is 0? Would you mind to post it as answer? I am a little confused

Comment: what you are trying to do is call the async task inside the forEach loop, modify busLeft in that method and get the result of that async method back inside the same loop. It will not be quiet easy.

Comment: @user3932668 I've edited the question already. With the code in edited portion, I am getting error message undefined is not a function at the callback() in moveNext(). Any ideas?

Comment: why did you add a callback there? I am used to using async module for nodejs server side programming for this kind of stuff. I have to look around for it. Please give me some time

Comment: beats me I would like to see a simple solution without any modules. you can add async module here and do async.eachSeries loop instead of forEach loop.

Comment: @user3932668 Sorry but would you mind to post a code solution as answer? Because I really have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69006/discussion-between-user3932668-and-i-was-so-lost).

Comment: About the last issue that you gave in chat:
the issue is that you are passing totalBusLoc in moveNext function
due to that the totalBusLoc inside that function is its local variable

Comment: @IWasSoLost: You are not passing a 'callback' argument to `moveNext`. What do you expect to happen at the `callback(totalBusLoc);` statement?